# How to save uploaded image in any particular folder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web dev and currently building a very basic page using Html/CSS and JS where users can upload the image and I can download it in my local system. But by default images are getting downloaded in the 'download' section of my desktop and I want to save them to any specific folder. How can I add this functionality?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just change the download destination of chrome, when you want to download those files?

Comment: Okay will try that, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You do not have access to other peoples file managers as that would be a major security risk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe I was unable to explain to you the end goal  I would be the one who will download the image and the user only has to upload it. So here I don't need access to other people's file managers. You got want I am saying?

Answer (score 0):

Uhh... You can't manipulate the download folder from frontend. It may be a security risk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done by Javascript (otherwise we could all produce websites which saved files all over a user's local PC).

As the end user in this case you can go into your browser and tell it which folder to save downloads in by default. (And remember to change it back if you want any other downloads to go elsewhere).

Here for example is what I find on Edge on Windows10 when going into Settings>Downloads:

[image]

Comment: I  think I didn't do a great job at explaining my problem. Actually, the user will only upload an image and I will be the one who will download it in my system, while doing that I want to download it in any specific folder. But by default, it is saving the image in the download section. Do you get what I am trying to say? Is there any way I can do this with HTML CSS like it automatically save it to a folder that I have created for the specific purpose?

Comment: Yes, I realised it was just you needing to do this, but the answer to  your query is still no, you need to tell the system where to put it via your browser (i.e. it needs user interaction, not just JS etc. on the local machine). Is there a problem with doing this (e.g. setting the default folder which tells the browser where to put stuff, you only need to do that once - until you want it to save things somewhere else).

Comment: Okay got it!! Thanks for explaining